# Change Project icon on Overview page

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am setting up a Project on Visual Studio Team Services.
On overview page, It has a project logo at the top left, it's seem create by a short name of full project name. I want to change this icon to own logo, but I has found no way to change it. Would you please help me let me know can we change this icon, if yes, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The best answer I found for Azure DevOps Server was to update the default team icon and perform a force-refresh (CTRL+F5). It appears a similar capability is on Azure DevOps Services.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/960724/view.html

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this functionality was removed as part the new navigation.

You can vote to have the feature added back here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/366277/change-project-icon-in-new-navigation.html

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is rolling out with the current deployment on VSTS. See the section "Custom Project image on Project description page" in our release notes at [Streamlined code and work items search – VSTS Sprint 124 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/oct-06-vsts):

> VSTS has allowed you to upload a custom image for your Project (and
>   default team) for some time. However, this image was only visible on
>   the settings page. With this update, you will see the customized image
>   on the description page, which helps to give a unique identity to a
>   Project. If not customized, you will see an auto-generated image based
>   on the Project's name.

Comment: Even though the doc does mention it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2017/oct-06-vsts#custom-project-image-on-project-description-page it doesn't explain how to do it. I am unable to find it.

Comment: I found it after turning off the new navigation preview. Then when you go to the Project Settings Overview, you can click on the image. A popup will open allowing you to change it.

Comment: I just did that but, after switching back to the preview layout, the standard logo reappeared. Switched back to the old layout and it was there. Bummer. I like the new layout but having visually ambiguous icons for each project (i.e. random color, first letter) is sort of a step backward.

Comment: It looks to be "pending release" [as of Dec 3rd](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/279255/cant-update-project-image-in-new-navigation.html?childToView=397143#comment-397143).

Answer (score 0):

Take your project link (ex: https://xxx.visualstudio.com/RobocopProject) and append a `/_settings` to it, on the resulting page the icon will be clickable and editable.

[image]